# GStreamer - issue with saving .mp4 and HLS at the same time

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, rtsp

I have two pipelines that seperately create .mp4 and HLS from RTSP stream.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc \
location="..." \
is-live=true \
! queue \
! rtph264depay \
! tee \
name=t \
t. \
! h264parse \
! mpegtsmux \
! hlssink \
playlist-length=0 \
max-files=50000 \
target-duration=3 \
location='segment%05d.ts' \
playlist-location='playlist.m3u8'
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc \
location="..." \
is-live=true \
! queue \
! rtph264depay \
! tee \
name=t \
t. \
! h264parse \
! mp4mux \
fragment-duration=1 \
! filesink \
append=true \
location='video.mp4'
```

When I merge them they created neither files (only empty .mp4).
Any ideas what I am missing? What could be the issue?

Not working prototype:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc \
location="<source>" \
is-live=true \
! queue \
! rtph264depay \
! tee \
name=t \
t. \
! h264parse \
! mpegtsmux \
! hlssink \
playlist-length=0 \
max-files=50000 \
target-duration=3 \
location='segment%05d.ts' \
playlist-location='playlist.m3u8' \
t. \
! h264parse \
! mp4mux \
fragment-duration=1 \
! filesink \
append=true \
location='video.mp4'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in how you use `queue`. You can read more about it here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/coreelements/queue.html?gi-language=c

This code works:

```
location="<source>" \
is-live=true \
! rtph264depay \
! tee \
name=t \
t. \
! queue \
! h264parse \
! mpegtsmux \
! hlssink \
playlist-length=0 \
max-files=50000 \
target-duration=3 \
location='segment%05d.ts' \
playlist-location='playlist.m3u8' \
t. \
! queue \
! h264parse \
! mp4mux \
fragment-duration=1 \
! filesink \
append=true \
location='video.mp4'
```